# Can't share image from dataDirectory via SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a Cordova android project and using [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) to share images

I'm storing images in dataDirectory. But when sharing image, it won't shares!

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share('', 'subject', window.cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'folder/image.jpg');
```

Share popup appears and I can select an app, subject will share but image won't!

If I share an image from www folder, it works fine.

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used share with image data method:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, 'Android filename', 'data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMALMBAP8AAP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAUKAAEALAAAAAAMAAwAQAQZMMhJK7iY4p3nlZ8XgmNlnibXdVqolmhcRQA7', null);
```

Note: passing a base64 file as 'data:' is not supported on Android 2.x

You can see here how to [Get base64 image data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/1016287)

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding `files/` in the final path and it works for me:

```
window.cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'files/folder/image.jpg'
```